# Output ~ string

Tags: c#

I am trying to output the string below, but it comes out as two lines without the `~` character.

```
test

car
```

**C# Code**

```
string mystring = "test~car";
SendKeys.SendWait(mystring + "{Enter}");
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}).

So, this should work:

```
string mystring = "test{~}car";
SendKeys.SendWait(mystring + "{Enter}");
```

Answer (score 2):

`~` has semantic meaning for `SendKeys` (as `ENTER`) so must be escaped:

```
string mystring = "test{~}car";
```